# Setting library list using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, db2

I read [in the docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/r0060653.html) that you must set the `SystemNaming` property to true to use the library list attribute in the connection string.  I don't see a way to do that using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore.

In appsettings:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CodeCamp": "Server=serverURL.com:446; Database=DB; UID=user; PWD=password; LibraryList=MyLib;"
```

In DBContext.cs

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseDb2(_config.GetConnectionString("CodeCamp"),
    p =>
    {
        p.SetServerInfo(IBMDBServerType.AS400, IBMDBServerVersion.AS400_07_01);
        p.UseRowNumberForPaging();
        p.MaxBatchSize(1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the connection-string to `UseDb2`, you should declare a `DB2Connection`. This connection will allow you to set `SystemNaming`. Then you can pass the `DB2Connection` to `UseDb2`. This requires [IBM.Data.DB2.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/) package.

```
DB2Connection connection = new DB2Connection(connectionString);
connection.SystemNaming = true;
optionsBuilder.UseDb2(connection,
    p =>
    {
        p.SetServerInfo(IBMDBServerType.AS400, IBMDBServerVersion.AS400_07_01);
        p.UseRowNumberForPaging();
        p.MaxBatchSize(1);
    });
```

Comment: Passing the IBM.Data.DB2.Core I have a `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Command' to type 'IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Command`